# Build executable JAR using Gradle: Vaadin & Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, vaadin

I'm having problems with building an executable JAR for my project that uses Vaadin 24 & Spring Boot 3. Build tool is Gradle.

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'com.vaadin' version '24.1.10'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '1.0.0'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

ext {
    set('vaadinVersion', "24.1.3")
    set('jjwtVersion', "0.11.5")
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.demo.alkolicznik.AlkolicznikApplication"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Spring
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.1'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.javamoney:moneta:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.16.1'
    testImplementation 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.7.2'
    testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.2'

    // required for TestRestTemplate to disable redirects
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1'

    // ImageKit API + enable handling of .webp images
    implementation 'com.github.imagekit-developer:imagekit-java:2.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.sejda.imageio', name: 'webp-imageio', version: '0.1.6'

    // JWT
    implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:${jjwtVersion}"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:${jjwtVersion}"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:${jjwtVersion}"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What I've tried.

1. `gradle bootJar`

This creates a JAR file under `/build/libs`, but launching it (`java -jar alkolicznik-1.0.0.jar`) results in this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:191) ~[vaadin-spring-24.1.4.jar!/:na]
        ...
    ...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

  Failed to find the following files:
      - ./generated/jar-resources/lit-renderer.ts
      - ./generated/jar-resources/gridConnector.js
      - ...
  Locations searched were:
      - `C:\Users\...\...\alkolicznik\frontend` in this project
      - `META-INF/frontend` in included JARs
      - `META-INF/resources/frontend` in included JARs

  Please, double check that those files exist. If you use a custom directory for your resource files instead of default `frontend` folder then make sure you it's correctly configured (e.g. set 'vaadin.frontend.frontend.folder' property)


        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315) ~[na:na]
        ...
    ...
```

2. `gradle bootJar` with properties

```
vaadin.productionMode=true
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true
vaadin.frontend.hotdeploy=false
vaadin.compatibilityMode=false
```

This produces `java.io.IOException: Unable to find index.html. It should be available on the classpath when running in production mode`.

3. `gradle -DproductionMode=true vaadinBuildFrontend build`

This actually works almost perfectly. The application is launched w/o erros, I can access it on web, but I've noticed that `Notifications` (Vaadin class) do not work and I use them quite extensively in the project.